# Why does my macbook pro screen flash when I start it up?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have looked at the other questions, but none of them have done me any good. I have been having an issue lately. When i start up my macbook pro (2009 or 2010 i think), it will start up nice, then it'll have a spinning thing under the apple like usual, and then the screen will literally flash. It will go white/black/white/black/white/black 3 times just as i described. It will then go to 100% brightness, and lessen itself back to what I have it set as. I've tried SMC reset, but not sure if it actually worked or not. I've read somewhere this could be some kind of video card issue, which i'm hoping it's not. Could someone please explain what is happening, and what I could do to fix this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: to find out if your SMC reset worked set the screen brightness to almost zero. If SMC reset worked it will change that setting

Comment: sounds like a problem with the graphic card or the ram

Comment: To find out what is going on, please provide a Console log for the time stamp of the event. You will probably see the "WidnowServer" switching your display modes and that is what we are interested in.